# I want to open an URL from Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

How can I open this url from ruby 1.9.2?

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/[customer number]/subscriptions -u sk_test.... -d plan=5555
```

I opened that url from my console. I used `curl [url]` and I didn't have any problem

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? What problem do you have? What is your question?

Comment: Hello spickerman. I want to open url from Ruby code, I tried with OpenURI, but I don't know how can I put this part <code>-u sk_test.... -d plan=5555</code> If I put it all like curl, I have been getting "Url is not correct"

Comment: is there a reason you don't want to use Stripe's Ruby API library?

Comment: I am using a gem for sprite, but It is old and it does not have the methods to subscriptions and I want to use curl calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Ruby's [net/http](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) library, which is rather low-level, or use a gem like [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client).

```
require 'rest-client'
RestClient.post 'http://user:password@example.com/resource', 'yourdata' , {:content_type => :xml}
```

**EDIT**

Unfortunately [OpenURI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) doesn't send POSTs, so you can't specify what would be a `--data` curl option. You can however use basic http authentication:
Authentication (equivalent to curl -u):

```
open("http://www.ruby-lang.org/",  :http_basic_authentication=>[user, password]) {|f|
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks brito, I have one question. How can I add -u [token] and -d plan=[plan] ? becasue if I put te url like this:

Comment: Thanks brito, I have one question. How can I add -u [token] and -d plan=[plan] ? becasue if I put this part <code>-u toke -d  plan together with all URL, I get error. The url is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
# Attributes you have to set
basic_auth_credentials = ['sk_test', 'password']
customer_number = 1234
data = { 'plan' => '5555' }

# Build and parse the URL
uri  = URI("https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/#{customer_number}/subscriptions")

# Build the POST request
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)

# Add form data to the POST request
request.set_form_data(data)

# Authenticate with http basic auth
request.basic_auth(*basic_auth_credentials)

# Build HTTP and set options to use HTTPS/SSL
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true

# You might consider using `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER` on production
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

# Finally do the request
response = http.request(request)
```